# Add html tags to list view row text

Tags: java, android

In my app i will create listview , the normal construction of string will be as bellow :

```
   final ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
String[] values = new String[] { "one", "two", "three",
    "four"};
```

but i want to add html tag to text appear on each row so i have to refer text to string as bellow  :

```
one.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.one)));
two.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.two)));
three.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.three)));
four.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.four)));
```

Which i mean the text appear in list view row can be can be created like :

```
  String[] values = new String[] { "one", "two", "three",
    "four"};
```

Or refered to string-arry as bellow :

```
<string-array name="days">
    <item>one</item>
    <item>two</item>
    <item>three</item>
    <item>four</item>
 </string-array>
```

**But this is not what i want** , i want to retrive text from string .xml which will be customized by html tag but i dont know what to write in class instead .

**UPDATE:**

AS answerd bellow i did it this way:

**MyArrayAdapter:**

```
public class MyArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
private final Activity context;
Typeface tf;
static class ViewHolder {
    public TextView text;
    }

public MyArrayAdapter(Activity context, String string) {
    super(context, R.layout.list_item);
    this.context = context;}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    tf=Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),"BFantezy.ttf"); 
    View rowView = convertView;
    if (rowView == null) {
      LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
      rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);

      int resourceToUse = R.string.day1;;
    switch(position){
      case 1: 
          resourceToUse = R.string.day1;
          break;
      case 2: 
          resourceToUse = R.string.day2;
          break;              
      case 3: 
          resourceToUse = R.string.day3;
          break;
      case 4: 
          resourceToUse = R.string.day4;         
      }
      TextView mTextView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.label);
      mTextView.setTypeface(tf); 
      mTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(context.getString(resourceToUse)));}


    return rowView;}}
```

**AndroidListViewActivity:**

```
public class AndroidListViewActivity extends ListActivity {
private String resourceToUse;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

     setListAdapter(new MyArrayAdapter(this,resourceToUse));  
                      }    
         }
```

IT GAVE : java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

LOGCAT:

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo
   {com.androidhive.androidlistview/com.androidhive.androidlistview.
   AndroidListViewActivity.java}:
   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
     com.androidhive.androidlistview.AndroidListViewActivity.java 
     in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.androidhive.androidlistview-          1.apk]
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1573)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:        
     com.androidhive.androidlistview.AndroidListViewActivity.
     java in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader
     [/data/app/com.androidhive.androidlistview-1.apk]
    at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1565)
... 11 more


          is there is any way to do it , any help will be appreciated , thanks
```

Comment: <string name="Mystring"><![CDATA[your html code here ]]>   
      </string>
      tv.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.Mystring))); You could try this code

Comment: @Raghunandan i know how to do it in string.xml but how to do it in class ,String[] values = new String[] {what to write herer},thanks

Comment: try this setText(Html.fromHtml(values[0])); But the string does not have any html tags

Comment: @androidqq6 if you could explain your question more I will help you

Comment: Pragnani post updated

Comment: @androidqq6 where is your html tags??

Comment: @Raghunandan already in string.xml with its html tag ,

Comment: @androidqq6  then use the method described in the first comment.

Comment: @androidqq6 You need to create a custom Adapter to achieve this..

Comment: @Raghunandan this method will written in class instead of  String[] values = new String[] { "one", "two", "three",
        "four"};

Comment: @androidqq6 http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getString(int). getString method takes an int as a argument

Comment: @Pragnani i need from that to able to format row text with html tag

Comment: @androidqq6 Please check Cruceo's answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override your ArrayAdapter's getView method, get the TextView associated with your item's position in the ListView, and then set the text from the String resource based on your current position:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
tf=Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),"BFantezy.ttf"); 
View rowView = convertView;
if (rowView == null) {
  LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
  rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
}
  int resourceToUse = R.string.day1;
switch(position){
  case 1: 
      resourceToUse = R.string.day1;
      break;
  case 2: 
      resourceToUse = R.string.day2;
      break;              
  case 3: 
      resourceToUse = R.string.day3;
      break;
  case 4: 
      resourceToUse = R.string.day4;
                         }

  TextView mTextView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.label);
  mTextView.setTypeface(tf); 
  mTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(context.getString(resourceToUse)));

  return rowView;  
}
```

Comment: would you please check update post , still i get error , thanks

Comment: I'm assuming it says resourceToUse might be null, so just set it to 0 during the initial declaration. Make sure to handle the null case though so you don't set the text on a null resource Id

Comment: i set it in my adapter to zero as: int resourceToUse = 0; but in AndroidListViewActivity class the problem i set it like this :private static final String resourceToUse = null; setListAdapter(new MyArrayAdapter(this, resourceToUse)); but still not show list and logcat error

Comment: Get rid of this whole thing: setListAdapter(new MyArrayAdapter(this, resourceToUse)); resourceToUse has nothing to do with the adapter and that whole extra String is unnecessary. Try declaring int resourceToUse = R.string.day1; since 4 is probably not an actual resource number. And your other stuff is a little messed up. I'm going to redo it for you...

Comment: That's what your getView() method should look like (you should also set your TypeFace as a global variable and only set it once, instead of re-creating the asset every time getView() is called for efficiency. What specific line is actually causing you to get a ClassNotFoundError and what is the logcat?

Comment: Is AndroidListViewActivity declared in your Manifest file as an Activity?

Comment: If they're in the same package, try cleaning the application: Project > Clean

Comment: (you should also set your TypeFace as a global variable ), do you mean use font factory class instead

Comment: I mean set "tf=Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),"BFantezy.ttf"); " in your constructor, instead of in your getView() method, as that will be called a lot, and there's no need for recreating those resources every single time if you're going to use it for every one.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear enough. But as far as I can understand, you want to get the string array declared in your `strings.xml` in your adapter. To do that first you need to create an array in the `strings.xml` similar to

```
<string-array name="numbers">
        <item>one</item>
        <item>two</item>
        <item>three</item>
        <item>four</item>
    </string-array>
```

Then you can get the string array in your code as

```
String values[] = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.numbers);
```

You can use this values array in the `getView()` of your adapter. I am still not sure if I answered your doubt or not. If not feel free to comment.